# Python comparing and building verfied list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I am attempting to sort a largish amount of data, 1 million+ images, into the only relevant media.

To achieve this I have created a dictionary structure, that is housing all the data for these images. This part is fine, however I am struggling to get only the relevant images into a new condensed list. So below is some sample data that is read into the script.

```
100653067_00.jpg | (671, 900) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\100653067_00.jpg
100653067_01.jpg | (656, 900) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\100653067_01.jpg
100653067_02.jpg | (660, 900) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\100653067_02.jpg
1008661118_00.jpg | (500, 448) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\1008661118_00.jpg
1008668062_00.jpg | (1500, 1120) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\1008668062_00.jpg
1008669063_00.jpg | (1500, 1120) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\1008669063_00.jpg
101020202_00.jpg | (1000, 760) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\101020202_00.jpg
1008668062_01.jpg | (100, 110) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\1008668062_01.jpg
1008669063_001.jpg | (100, 110) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\1008669063_001.jpg
101020202_01.jpg | (504, 750) | D://media/pr/product\1\0\101020202_01.jpg
```

I am having issues taking only the largest image, i.e. comparing the ID values. For example 101020202_00.jpg should be taken over 101020202_01.jpg as it has the largest overall size.

```
for item in img_dict:
    tempStore = img_dict[item]
    locationVar = ''
    idVar = ''
    for item in img_dict:
        i = img_dict[item]
        if re.match(tempStore['ID']+"([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)", i['ID']):
            if tempStore['Resolution X'] > i['Resolution X'] or tempStore['Resolution Y'] > i['Resolution Y']:
                locationVar = tempStore['Location']
                idVar = tempStore['ID']

    highestResFile[idVar] = {'ID':idVar, 'Location': locationVar}
```

An example of what img_dict outputs:

```
{'000002353911_1': {'ID': '000002353911_1',
                    'Image Name': '000002353911_1.jpg',
                    'Location': 'D://media/pr/product\\0\\0\\000002353911_1.jpg',
                    'Resolution X': 406,
                    'Resolution Y': 406},
 '000002355373_1': {'ID': '000002355373_1',
                    'Image Name': '000002355373_1.jpg',
                    'Location': 'D://media/pr/product\\0\\0\\000002355373_1.jpg',
                    'Resolution X': 406,
                    'Resolution Y': 406}}
```

Comment: Can you show us the conetnts of `img_dict`?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, but I think the essential core idea is to organize items by their "base name" so you don't have to iterate through all one million items to find ones that need to be compared. "foo_1.jpg" and "foo_23.jpg" have the same base name, so you should be comparing them to one another, but not to "bar_42.jpg". Using the base name as the key to a dictionary seems like the logical choice.

```
import re

def size(item):
    return item["dimensions"][0] * item["dimensions"][1]

data = {}
with open("data.dat") as file:
    for line in file:
        filename, raw_dimensions, path = line.strip().split(" | ")
        dimensions = [int(x) for x in re.match(r"\((\d*), (\d*)\)", raw_dimensions).groups()]
        base_name = filename.partition("_")[0]
        item = {
            "filename": filename,
            "base_name": base_name,
            "dimensions": dimensions,
            "path": path
        }
        if base_name not in data or size(item) > size(data[base_name]):
            data[base_name] = item

print(list(data.values()))
```

Result (whitespace added by me for clarity:):

```
[
    {'path': 'D://media/pr/product\\1\\0\\101020202_00.jpg',  'dimensions': [1000,  760], 'base_name': '101020202',  'filename': '101020202_00.jpg'}, 
    {'path': 'D://media/pr/product\\1\\0\\1008669063_00.jpg', 'dimensions': [1500, 1120], 'base_name': '1008669063', 'filename': '1008669063_00.jpg'}, 
    {'path': 'D://media/pr/product\\1\\0\\1008661118_00.jpg', 'dimensions': [500,   448], 'base_name': '1008661118', 'filename': '1008661118_00.jpg'}, 
    {'path': 'D://media/pr/product\\1\\0\\1008668062_00.jpg', 'dimensions': [1500, 1120], 'base_name': '1008668062', 'filename': '1008668062_00.jpg'}, 
    {'path': 'D://media/pr/product\\1\\0\\100653067_00.jpg',  'dimensions': [671,   900], 'base_name': '100653067',  'filename': '100653067_00.jpg'}
]
```

Comment: I'm going to try implement this into my code tomorrow. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I appear to be getting the following error when running it on a large sample size of data:     filename, raw_dimensions, path = line.strip().split(" | ")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: My code assumes that every line in your input file contains exactly two pipe characters, each of which has a space to either side. If you have any lines that have more than that, or if you have any blank lines, the code will fail at that point.

Comment: That's the unusual thing, it should have exactly two pipe characters. I'll check what's going on, but I imagine some line has something funny on it. Thanks for the help.